Family of separable Hilbert spaces over locally compact form a continuous field of Hilbert space?
Let $\{H_{x}\}_{x\in G^{0}}$ be a family of separable Hilbert spaces and $G^{0}$ be a locally compact second countable topological space. Let $\mathbb{B}_{x}$ be the orthonormal basis of $H_{x}$.
If we define a collection of vector fields  $\Gamma$ from $G^{0}$ to $H=\cup_{x\in X}H_{x}$ such that for $f\in \Gamma$, $f(x)\in \mathbb{B}_{x}$, then obviously $x\to \|f(x)\|_{H_{x}}$ is a continuous function since $\|f(x)\|_{H_{x}}=1$ for every $x$.
So Can this family $\{H_{x}\}$ form a continuous field of Hilbert space with the continuous sections being the linear span of elements in $\Gamma$?
Here, is the definition of a continuous field of Banach space:


In general no. By polarization identity, if this forms a continuous field and if $f, g \in \Gamma$, then $\langle f(x), g(x) \rangle$ should be continuous on $G^0$. But this function is ${0, 1}$-valued, so that puts a high constraint on the topology of $G^0$ as well as the specific choice of $\Gamma$.

Yes, right. Thank you. I think it is possible if the fibers are isometrically isomorphic over a neighborhood

How would that help? All separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic to each other. It certainly does nothing to resolve the point in my previous comment.
